Compare the column 2 of File 1 with column 4 and 5 of file 2
I have a tab delimited file_1
NC_025       4569   .   KX838946.2      
NC_025       16546  .   KJ641660.1      
NC_025       11996  .   KX932454.2

file_2
NC_025.1     RefSeq  gene    5690    7513    .       +       .       ID=gene-NZ82_gp4;Dbxref=GeneID:20964334;Name=NZ82_gp4;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=NZ82_gp4
NC_025.1     RefSeq  gene    4612    10046   .       +       .       ID=gene-NZ82_gp5;Dbxref=GeneID:20964335;Name=NZ82_gp5;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=NZ82_gp5
NC_025.1     RefSeq  gene    10337   16933   .       +       .       ID=gene-NZ82_gp6;Dbxref=GeneID:20964336;Name=NZ82_gp6;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=NZ82_gp6
NC_025.1     RefSeq  gene    9000    12000    .      +       .       ID=gene-AL82_gp5;Dbxref=GeneID:109647334;Name=AL82_gp5;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=AL82_gp5

I want to compare column 2 of file 1 with column 4 and 5 of file 2. If column 2 of file_1 is >= column 4 and <= column5 of same row of file 2, I want to combine the whole line of file_1 and file_2
NC_025       16546   .   KJ641660.1     NC_025.1     RefSeq  gene    10337   16933   .       +       .       ID=gene-NZ82_gp6;Dbxref=GeneID:20964336;Name=NZ82_gp6;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=1NZ82_gp6    
NC_025       11996   .   KX932454.2     NC_025.1     RefSeq  gene    10337   16933   .       +       .       ID=gene-NZ82_gp6;Dbxref=GeneID:20964336;Name=NZ82_gp6;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=1NZ82_gp6
NC_025       11996   .   KX932454.2     NC_025.1     RefSeq  gene    9000    12000    .       +       .       ID=gene-AL82_gp5;Dbxref=GeneID:109647334;Name=AL82_gp5;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=AL82_gp5

I have tried :
awk '{
  if (NR==FNR) {
  l[NR]=$0
  a[NR]=$2
 }
  else if (a[FNR]>=$4 && a[FNR]<=$5) {
  print l[FNR],$0
 }
}' file_1 file_2 > File_3

But it prints nothing.

although your code could be shortened, it produces output on your sample data. You might want to set OFS="\t" or use l[FNR] "\t" $0

Never name a variable l, it looks far too much like the number 1 and so obfuscates your code.

changed sample still produces output for me. what is output of date >File_3; cat File_3 run in the same directory?

you should probably also set -F'\t' to avoid problems with spaces changing the column count

Should the first output field REALLY be the value from the 2nd file (NC_025.1) rather than the value from the first file (NC_025)? If not, please fix that as it impacts every potential solution.

Right now it looks like you want to compare the 2 files line-by-line (i.e. compare line 3 of file 1 with line 3 of file 2), hence the paste answer you have so far but which you say doesn't work for you. If that's not the case and you want to compare all of the column 2s from file 1 against all of the column 4s/5s from file 2 then [edit] your question to show a [mcve] that demonstrates that functionality.

These look quite similar to many other basic bioinformatics questions. If you can tell us what here file types are called (BAM? Chloropleth? Fastn? etc) we can probably find existing duplicates.

So, you basically want to join all lines using a range criteria. After storing the first file, you need to iterate over its lines for each line in the second file.
awk '
  NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; p[NR]=$2; next}
          {for (n in a) if ($4<=p[n] && p[n]<=$5) print a[n] "\t" $0}
' file_1.txt file_2.txt > file_3.txt


@RaviSaroch this code also produces your requested output with your sample data, it is not clear what you mean by "It searches the entire column" : $ accesses fields of the current line

@jhnc I THINK they mean they want to compare the values of the file 1 column across the applicable columns across the whole of file 2, not just against the columns on the same line number in file 2, but it's not clear yet from the question. I think when they say "of same row of file 2" in the question they mean that the column 4 and column 5 from file 2 being compared to the column 2 from file 1 are on the same row as each other, not that they're on the same row as the column 2 from file 1. But idk....

@EdMorton it's possible, but with the sample input provided, your interpretation would seem to want two lines of sample output (line 2 and 3 of first file both match line 3 of second)

@jhnc good point. idk then, guess we'll see what the OP tells us.

If the value in column 2 of file 1 is greater than the value in column 4 at row 30 of file_2, it must be less than column 5 at the same row number (30).

"column 2 of file 1" - we know that but what we're debating is of which row(s) in file 1? Column 2 of ONLY row 30 in file 1 or column 2 of ANY row in file 1 or something else?

column 2 of any row(s) in file 1

The value in row 3 (11996) of file 1 is greater than the value in column 4 (10337) and less than the value in column 5 (16933). Similarly, the criteria are also fulfilled at line 4 of file 2, in which the value of file 1 (11996) is greater than the value in row 4 (9000) and less than at column 5 (12000).

@Ravi Ok, but why is the first line of file_1 then missing in the output, as its value 4569 is clearly between the values 3016 and 10046 from the second line of file_2?

@pmf I have updated file 2; now, it does not fit the criteria and is not included in the output file.
